# CCXT structure for meteor applications

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, meteor, cryptocurrency

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Programming Language version: Meteor.js 1.7.03

CCXT version: Latest 1.15 or whatever

Exchange: Most of them

Method: Pulling Transaction Data, and most public pricing endpoints

I wanted to use the ccxt crypto library for my meteor application.

I wanted to know how would you structure this library in a meteor application. I wanted to know how to structure the server side code so that I could pull transaction history from the private endpoints at the user's request. The user would be able to choose their desired exchange and it will allow them to put in their API key and secret.

I also wanted to know how to structure to pull pricing data from public endpoints. I intend to make a live feed for this data.

Do I separate the files based off the exchange or methods and call the files required dependant on the action.

Is there an example or guide that I could base it off of or any recommendations.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are familiar with pub / sub system and use of meteor methods, nothing out of the ordinary here, you could put the API call on the server and based on user actions fire appropriate meteor method to make API call